# Keen-io JS visualization showing no hits

Tags: keen-io

I'm trying to output a chart from Keen.io using the JS visualizations, and it generates a chart fine, except it shows no hits.  I've checked the stats in the keen.io admin, and there are most definitely pageview hits within the defined range (last 7 days) under the defined projectID (currently the only project on the account).  And I've double-checked the project ID to make sure no issues there--plus it was copy/pasted from a page that's recording hits, which is working fine.  This is the current code:

```
Keen.ready(function(){

var total_pageviews = new Keen.Query("count", {
  eventCollection: "pageviews",
  timeframe: "this_7_days",
  interval: "daily"
});

client.draw(total_pageviews, document.getElementById("showcase-areachart"), {
  chartType: "areachart",
  title: "Showcase Ad Impressions (7 days)",
  chartOptions: {
    isStacked: true
  }
});

});
```

I originally had additional filters, but have removed them to narrow down  possible issues while debugging why it's not finding hits.  As-is, it looks like it should show a chart with all pageviews from the collection within the last 7 days.  Currently the chart shows a static line at 0 for the entire 7 days.

Any ideas where/what the issue might be?

From Inspect > Network, I see two "count" items from api.keen.io, one content-type "text/html; charset=UTF-8", which has a blank response, and one "application/json".  The JSON one shows the following response:

```
{"result": [{"value": 0, "timeframe": {"start": "2015-12-03T08:00:00.000Z", "end": "2015-12-04T08:00:00.000Z"}}, {"value": 0, "timeframe": {"start": "2015-12-04T08:00:00.000Z", "end": "2015-12-05T08:00:00.000Z"}}, {"value": 0, "timeframe": {"start": "2015-12-05T08:00:00.000Z", "end": "2015-12-06T08:00:00.000Z"}}, {"value": 0, "timeframe": {"start": "2015-12-06T08:00:00.000Z", "end": "2015-12-07T08:00:00.000Z"}}, {"value": 0, "timeframe": {"start": "2015-12-07T08:00:00.000Z", "end": "2015-12-08T08:00:00.000Z"}}, {"value": 0, "timeframe": {"start": "2015-12-08T08:00:00.000Z", "end": "2015-12-09T08:00:00.000Z"}}, {"value": 0, "timeframe": {"start": "2015-12-09T08:00:00.000Z", "end": "2015-12-10T08:00:00.000Z"}}]}
```

Comment: if you inspect your page and view the network tab does it display any errors or anything in there? this will let you know if your data is at least coming through.

Comment: The inspector in Chrome doesn't list any issues there, although when I check in Firefox, on the keen.io item with the JSON, if I go to the response tab on that it says this:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

The same spot in Chrome just lists the JSON response, which appears to show an entry for each day, with no hits for each.

Comment: could you edit your question and post both of the response you are receiving, please? Note: remove any sensitive data before posting

Comment: I updated the information in the original post.  I'm no longer getting the error I mentioned in FireFox though, that's showing the same JSON response as Chrome now.

Comment: and you know you have data in there for those timeframes?

Comment: Yes, I just checked each of the 7 days listed there via the Explorer page in the keen.io admin, and the number of results it shows for each of those days are: 22, 59, 1, 1, 0, 8, 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because you are querying a collection called "pageviews" but your collection is named "pageview".